# Powershell Large Binary string conversion to Integer/hexadecimal

Tags: powershell, binary, hex, number-formatting

I'm about at my wits end with this.
I need a binary string that is 32 characters long converted to Hexadecimal in powershell. For example: `"000010000000001111101000100010"`

I consistently get `Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.` or INT32 depending on which I use.

Is there any good way to do this in PowerShell?
I've been running it as so:

```
$updatedHexsize = [Convert]::ToInt64("000010000000001111101000100010",10)
```

Perhaps there is a manual approach?

Comment: Why are you using `10` as the 2nd argument ? Maybe you meant `2` ? like `[Convert]::ToInt64('000010000000001111101000100010', 2).ToString('X')`

Comment: OMG thank you so much. For some reason I was thinking that argument was telling the system what Base to convert the value to. Its working now you rock!

Comment: I've done it for this post, but please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the future.

Answer (score 1):

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) has provided the solution in a comment:

Use `2`, not `10`, as the number-base argument in your [`[Convert]::ToInt64()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Convert.ToInt64) call, to **match the base of the *input* string representation**, then ***reformat* the numeric result as a *hexadecimal* string** (base `16`, with [`.ToString('X')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.int64.tostring#system-int64-tostring(system-string))):

```bash
# -> '200FA22'
[Convert]::ToInt64('000010000000001111101000100010', 2).ToString('X')
```

Alternative, via the `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), with a `0x` prefix:

```bash
# -> '0x200FA22'
'0x{0:X}' -f [Convert]::ToInt64('000010000000001111101000100010', 2)
```

`0x` is used literally, and `{0:X}` is a placeholder for the first (and here only) operand (`{0}` if no formatting were to be applied), with `X` being the [standard numeric format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) that requests hex formatting (with uppercase hex digits; use `x` for lowercase).

---

###### Background information:

> I was thinking that argument [`10`, changed to `2` above] was telling the system what Base to convert the value to.

- [`[Convert]::ToInt64()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Convert.ToInt64) by definition returns a *number* (of type [`System.Int64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Int64)) and **a number has *no* intrinsic base.**
- A **base only comes into play when choosing a human-readable *representation* of a number**, of necessity **as a *string***.
- Conversely, in order **to *unambiguously* convert a given string representation back to a number**, the **base** that was chosen for the representation **must be indicated** - either "out of band", i.e. **via a separate parameter**, as in the case at hand - **or via a base-specific *prefix***.

  - PowerShell supports two base prefixes (case-insensitively) in number *literals*, in source code:

    - **`0x` for *hex* (hexadecimal) numbers** (base `16`; e.g. `0xA` is the same as decimal `10`)
    - In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only: **`0b` for *binary* numbers** (base `2`; e.g. `0b10` is the same as decimal `2`).
    - Number literals that start with neither are interpreted as *decimal* numbers (base `10`)
    - Additionally and separately, the specific number *type* can be indicated with a type-specifier *suffix* (e.g., the `l` in `10l` indicates a `[long]` aka `[System.Int64]` value) - see the conceptual [about_Numeric_Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Numeric_Literals) help topic for details.
  - **PowerShell's flexible *casts* can be applied directly to strings**, which, if the target type is numeric, are parsed *as if they were number literals*. Therefore, in PowerShell 7+ you could do the following:

    ```bash
    # PowerShell 7+ only. Note the '0b' prefix.
    # -> '200FA22'
    ([Int64] '0b000010000000001111101000100010').ToString('X')
    ```